# Angular-Cli based Lazy loaded AOT named bundle creation

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, bundling-and-minification, chunks

Problem Statement:
Finding a way to add custom naming to AOT based bundle chunks for lazy loaded routes from an Angular-Cli based project.

Details:
If you use Angular-Cli with routeModule loadChildren() functionality for lazy loading these chunks, all the chunks are being created using 'id'/'hashcode' and thus we get 1.chunk.js, 2.chunk.js etc.

I need to name these chunks based on the module name(ideally on each route) and they should be AOT modules.

I get to a point where using legacy require.ensure(), i am able to created 'Named Chunks' for JIT  but nothing concrete on AOT although Dynamic Import using import() function gives some hope.

But not able to make it work on my configured routes using routerModule. So does anyone knows, how can we create custom named AOT chunks from a route configuration?

e.g my route will look like this-

```
{ path: 'child', loadChildren: 'app/child/child.module#ChildModule' }
```

i want to have a AOT chunk named "ChildModule".

Comment: Update your angular-cli to 1.3.0-beta.1.https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.3.0-beta.1 See also https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6700